# url encoding is not working when sending an URL to WhatsApp

Tags: php, whatsapp, url-encoding

I want to share an URL via WhatsApp. Sending a normal text is working fine, but sending an URL is not working. How can I create a working WhatsApp link with an URL? I tried to do it like this, but it does not work:

```
<?php
$value = 2;
$productId = base64_encode($value);
?>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.domain.com/products.php?productId=. <?php urlencode($productId) ?>">Share To WhatsApp</a>
```

Comment: Don't you need to `urlencode` everything coming after `text=`?

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca I tried without `urlencode` that time also i am getting like this `www.domain.com/products.php?productId`

Comment: Of course the whole parameter value needs to be encoded, everything else just doesn’t make sense. // Please go read [ask] - so far, you have not even managed to give us a proper problem description - “is not happening” and “time also i am getting like this” are _not_ one. (My _guess_ would be that you should probably use a proper, absolute URL to begin with ...)

Comment: You forgot to echo the urlencode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must encode the whole value of the text query parameter, not only the number (which doesn't do anything). Do it like that:

```
<?php
$value = 2;
$text = urlencode("www.domain.com/products.php?productId=".$value);
?>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo $text; ?>">Share To WhatsApp</a>
```

Comment: I am getting `This link is incorrect. Close this window and try a different link.`

Comment: it looks like it is correct according to the docs. However, I had a small typo in my code, which I just fixed, try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Just Use The rawurlencode() instead of urlencode() 
Example

```
<?php
$value = 2;
$text = rawurlencode("www.domain.com/products.php?productId=".$value);
?>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo $text; ?>"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
```